# Jedis connections not being released

Tags: redis, jedis

I am having issues using Redis with a Jedis connection pool.

The behaviour I am seeing is that after connections are established they are not being released back into the connection pool.

I know this because using the `redis-cli client list` command I can see the connections still hanging around.

Can someone please review my jedis connection pool to let me know if that might be causing the issue.

```
     <spring:bean id="ElasticachePoolConfig" name="ElasticachePoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig" >

        <!-- Minimum number of idle connections to Redis - these can be seen as always open and ready to serve -->
        <spring:property name="minIdle" value="${redis.minIdle}" />

        <!-- Number of connections to Redis that just sit there and do nothing -->
        <spring:property name="maxIdle" value="${redis.maxIdle}" />

        <!-- Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time -->
        <spring:property name="maxTotal" value="${redis.maxTotal}" />

        <!-- The minimum amount of time an object may sit idle in the pool before it is eligable for eviction by the idle object evictor.--> 
        <spring:property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="${redis.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis}" />

        <!-- The minimum amount of time a connection may sit idle in the pool before it is eligible for eviction by the idle connection evictor -->
        <spring:property name="softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="${redis.softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis}" />

        <!-- The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before throwing an exception -->
        <spring:property name="maxWaitMillis" value="${redis.maxWaitMillis}" />

        <!-- Maximum number of connections to test in each idle check -->
        <spring:property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="${redis.numTestsPerEvictionRun}" />

        <!-- Tests whether connection is dead when connection retrieval method is called -->
        <spring:property name="testOnBorrow" value="${redis.testOnBorrow}" />

        <!-- Tests whether connection is dead when returning a connection to the pool -->
        <spring:property name="testOnReturn" value="${redis.testOnReturn}" />

        <!-- Tests whether connections are dead during idle periods -->
        <spring:property name="testWhileIdle" value="${redis.testWhileIdle}" />

        <!-- Idle connection checking period -->
        <spring:property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${redis.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}" />

        <spring:property name="blockWhenExhausted" value="${redis.blockWhenExhausted}" />

     </spring:bean>
```

Where the properties are set as follows...

```
redis.port=6379
redis.timeout=2000
redis.ttl=600
redis.host=localhost
redis.repeater.maxRetries=3
redis.repeater.millisBetweenRetries=2000
redis.minIdle=5
redis.maxIdle=10
redis.maxTotal=8
redis.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=30000
redis.softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis=-1
redis.maxWaitMillis=5000
redis.numTestsPerEvictionRun=10
redis.testOnBorrow=true
redis.testOnReturn=true
redis.testWhileIdle=false
redis.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=50000
redis.blockWhenExhausted=true
```

Comment: "The behaviour I am seeing is that after connections are established they are not being released back into the connection pool. I know this because using the redis-cli client list command I can see the connections still hanging around." Non sequitur. The connections are supposed to stay around. You put *open* connections back into a connection pool, not closed ones :)

Comment: Hi @hobbs thanks for responding. You're right. But shouldn't the connections drop back down to my min idle connections when eviction runs?

Comment: it should drop down to no more than `maxIdle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `maxIdle` setting is larger than your `maxTotal` setting, so effectively no connections will be released on idle.  The pool will maintain `maxIdle` connections.

JedisPool uses Apache Commons Pooling internally.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364855/what-is-the-difference-between-maxtotal-and-maxidle-in-apache-commons-pool-2) regarding the differences between `maxIdle` and `maxTotal`.